# OpenCV Mat data address shows weird value

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm suffered by using OpenCV Mat due to unexpected results.

There is an example code:

```
cv::Mat local_mat = cv::Mat::eye(cv::Size(1000, 1000), CV_8UC1);
qDebug() << "1. local_mat.data: " << local_mat.data;

cv::Mat sobel_img_ = cv::Mat::eye(cv::Size(1000, 1000), CV_8UC1);
qDebug() << "2. sobel_img_.data: " << sobel_img_.data;

sobel_img_ = local_mat; // copy address but no clone()
qDebug() << "3. sobel_img_.data: " << sobel_img_.data;

sobel_img_ = cv::Mat::eye(cv::Size(1000, 1000), CV_8UC1); // renew
qDebug() << "4. sobel_img_.data: " << sobel_img_.data;
```

> 1. local_mat.data:  0x55aa19a53e40
> 2. sobel_img_.data:  0x55aa19b480c0
> 3. sobel_img_.data:  0x55aa19a53e40
> 4. sobel_img_.data:  0x55aa19a53e40

1 and 2 should be different because I create new Mat(), so it is fine.

However, 3 and 4 are same even though I create new Mat() after copying the local_mat into sobel_mat.

I meet many problems like this when I use OpenCV Mat.

Could you explain why it happens and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializing of matrix is a form of [matrix expression](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html).

`cv::Mat` has overloads of `operator=`. One of them handles [MatExpr](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a2a0798475170fb3a23b5bc63686de334) as its argument:

> Assigned matrix expression object. As opposite to the first form of
> the assignment operation, the second form **can reuse already allocated
> matrix if it has the right size and type to fit the matrix expression
> result**. It is automatically handled by the real function that the
> matrix expressions is expanded to. For example, C=A+B is expanded to
> add(A, B, C), and add takes care of automatic C reallocation.

by bold font I emphasized what happens in your case. Already allocated memory is used to create identity matrix by `cv::Eye`.

You can turn `MatExpr` into `cv::Mat` just by casting:

```
sobel_img_ = (cv::Mat)cv::Mat::eye(cv::Size(1000, 1000), CV_8UC1); // renew
```

then `sobel_img` will refer to new allocated matrix.